# Most efficient way to get csv data to the backend

Tags: php, csv, parsing, laravel-5

I wanted to see if I could get some input from the community regarding the upload of a CSV file.  These files are huge, talking multiple GB.  Due to server restrictions, I am unable to use chunk uploading.

So lets say I have a very standard file input

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="fileToUpload">
```

On change or submit, I can then pass this via a route to my backend.  The Controller function might look something like this

```
public function uploadFilePost(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'fileToUpload' => 'required|file',
    ]);

    $request->fileToUpload->store('csvFiles');

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully uploaded the file.');
}
```

The big issue here is that with files of multiple GB, this process takes hours, and this is a problem as you need to keep your browser open whilst this request is happening.

So really my first question is this.  I am able to parse the file on the client using something like [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/docs).  This literally takes a few seconds to parse.  With the file now parsed into a JSON string or array, would this in any way reduce the size of the file?

My second question is say parsing does nothing to the size, I now however have all of this csv data within local variable.  Is there any way for me to send this to the backend without the user having to wait for hours?  I have looked at queues, would this be an option, or would this only do anything once the data is on the backed?

Really, any information is appreciated.  I may be way off in my thinking, I am just trying to come up with the most efficient way of sending a large volume of data to my backend.

Thanks

Comment: do other people need to be able to upload files, or just you?

Comment: You could try using web workers, they continue to work even after the page is closed.

So you would use extract the data as a large json object, then split it into chunks, and then send the data one by one to the server.

Comment: It would be other users uploading files.

Comment: I think a little more information is necessary.  Why can't you chunk the file?  What is the structure of the file?  Given that you can parse it on the client, perhaps there is some way to pass it in concurrent uploads, but still, multiple gig uploads are going to take time.